# Set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $S_n$ is convex

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, symmetric-matrices

I'd like to know if the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $S_n$ is convex.

I looked at the definition of a convex set and it says that a set $X$ is convex if $$\forall x,y \in X \, \forall \lambda \in [0,1]: \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in X$$
So for $A,B\in S_n$ we have that $$\underbrace{\lambda A}_{\in S_n} + \underbrace{(1-\lambda)B}_{\in S_n}\in S_n$$

because the product of a scalar and a symm. matrix is symmetric and also the sum of two symmetric matrices is symmetric.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: For me is correct

Comment: Assuming the matrices are real or complex valued this is correct. If the are rational or integer valued then any irrational $\lambda$ will violate closure.

Comment: Note: you just proved that any subspace is convex, and used the fact that $S_n$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{F}^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Well, to prove it you should show that $(\lambda A + (1-\lambda ) B)^T = \lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$. You could also notice that it is the kernel of the map $A \mapsto A-A^T$.

Comment: @copper.hat Why should I prove that? Is my proof not sufficient? Also notice, that I forgot to add that $S_n$ are real-valued $n\times n$ matrices